# ExtJS license issue

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

We need to develop a project for a government organisation that needs a javascript dev library to build the front end.

Having exploring quite a bit options in the market, we decided to go for ExtJS library as it provides an abundant set of widgets and UI tools that come in handy and ready to use. We also identified there are two licenses, one for Open source and the other for commercial use.

We are unsure which license to go for for our project. The project is not-for-profit and the established website will be open for use by public (which means the ExtJS and our own codes will be open?). We are not going to modify any part of ExtJS library source code, only just to use it.

Please help. Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that qualifies as open source.
However you should really be directing this at Sencha company.

Comment: I will get onto Sencha forum and post my question there, see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, open source ExtJS is under GPLv3. In most cases, the code has to be published on request which normally Government will not allow that. However, some cases the exception may apply. For example, if you are contractor hired by government.

To ensure you have correct license, please contact extjs licensing at  licensing@extjs.com

Normally,they will reply within 1-3 working days. I also had licensing issues before and they answered it in very details.